# Null Value DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagrid, vb.net-2010

good morning everyone

I`m having a little issue with a dgv. Im trying to fill it with the result of a function that shows the name of the files in a folder and the amount of lines each file has.

But for some reason im having a null vaule on the datagrid and i dont know how to remove it. I`ve been doing this without much knowledge of vb.net or coding whatsoever so any help would be greatly apreciated

Here is the code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.StreamReader
Imports System.IO.DirectoryInfo

Public Class MainForm

    'asigna la var como datatable
    Dim results1 As New DataTable

    Private Sub Boton_Buscar_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Boton_Buscar.Click

        'muestra el dialogo y guarda el dir
        FBD1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox1.Text = FBD1.SelectedPath
        FSW1.Path = TextBox1.Text

        'indica el datasource al datagrid
        Try
            DGV1.DataSource = GetLineCount()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    'devuelve archivos y su num de lineas
    Public Function GetLineCount() As DataTable

        results1.Columns.Add(0)
        results1.Columns.Add(1)


        'array para los tipos de archivo
        Dim MyFileArray As [String]() = New [String](7) {"*.txt", "*.doc", "*.docx", "*.odt", "*.pdf", "*.rtf", _
                                                       "*.csv", "*.vb"}

        'array para los directorios
        Dim MyDirectoryArray As [String]() = New [String](0) {TextBox1.Text}

        ' loop directorios
        For Each sd As [String] In MyDirectoryArray
            Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(sd)

            'loop los tipos de archivos
            For Each sFileType As [String] In MyFileArray

                'loop los archivos ante el contador
                For Each file__1 As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles(sFileType)

                    Dim LineCount = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file__1.FullName).Count()

                    'alimenta el datagrid con los datos nuevos
                    results1.Rows.Add()
                    results1.Rows.Add.Item(0) = "FileName: " & file__1.FullName
                    results1.Rows.Add.Item(1) = "LineCount: " & LineCount

                Next

            Next

        Next

        Return results1

    End Function

End Class
```

[And here is the output im getting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92g2i.jpg)

Any help is very welcome, have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting null values is that you're trying to add the row by one cell at a time.

Instead of

```
results1.Rows.Add()
results1.Rows.Add.Item(0) = "FileName: " & file__1.FullName
results1.Rows.Add.Item(1) = "LineCount: " & LineCount
```

Try

```
results1.Rows.Add("FileName: " & file__1.FullName, "LineCount: " & LineCount)
```

Your current code adds three rows instead of 1 each time: first an empty row, then a row with cell(0) filled and then null, and then a row with null and then cell(1) filled.

Comment: oh my god, it worked !. Thank you very much !!. You just made my day, thanks !!